# JDK7u21 RMI changes

Tags: java, rmi

The Release Notes of JDK7u21 specified the changes related to RMI:

> From this release, the RMI property java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly is
>   set to true by default. In previous releases the default value was
>   false.
>
> This change of default value may cause RMI-based applications to break
>   unexpectedly. The typical symptom is a stack trace that contains a
>   java.rmi.UnmarshalException containing a nested
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.
>
> If these exceptions occur, the preferred way to solve the problem is
>   to configure all RMI clients and servers to use the same codebase, by
>   specifying proper values in the java.rmi.server.codebase system
>   property. This is typically done by adding the -D option to the
>   command that starts up the application: java
>   -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:////(path-to-remote-classes)/

It also specified in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/enhancements-7.html) that workaround is to set the `java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly` property back to false.

However, even when I explicitly set this property to false, I am getting an exception mentioned above. Any clue here please?

And if I have to solve it by the preferred way described above (by setting the -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:////(path-to-remote-classes)/, then which path should I set over here? My workspace/bin?

Comment: Can someone here please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry, I solved it on my own. The problem was wrong number of parameters were being passed to my .ksh file. This caused the problem starting RMI registry.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure to set the properties on all JVMs that are using your remote classes. This includes your RMI server, the RMI clients, **and** the RMI registry. If they are all on the same machine, then you can set `java.rmi.server.codebase` on them all to a `file:` URL that points to the location of the classes. If they're not on the same machine, then you could make the classes available using an HTTP server, and then set the codebase property of the remote JVMs (presumably the clients) to use an `http:` URL that points to where the classes are available. Or you could make the classes available to remote JVMs through some other means, such as copying them, or using a shared filesystem, and then set the codebase property to a `file:` URL.

Your attempt to apply the workaround of setting `java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly` to `false` might not be working for a couple reasons: you might not have set it in all of the interacting JVMs, or you might not have set the codebase property to the right value.

Since you're having to go to the trouble of configuring the registry and all the clients, you might as well pursue setting their `codebase` property to the right URL, instead of pursuing the workaround of setting `useCodebaseOnly` to `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insight. I tried setting the java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly property correctly to false using System.setProperty() method and also using -D switch to JVM. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Additionally the RMI server, client and registry all are on the same machine in my case. So I tried to specify the codebase like this -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/ICS/bin. Is this syntax correct? Because it didn't fix it too.

Comment: The most likely problem is that the rmiregistry can't see your classes. You need to set the codebase property on the registry JVM. To set properties for the registry, the -D option must be prefixed with -J. Also, your URL syntax is wrong; it needs to have three leading slashes for local files, and a trailing slash if it's pointing to a directory. The command should be something like `rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:///C:/ICS/bin/` . For the client, the simplest thing is probably to add the necessary classes to the classpath.

Comment: If you continue to have difficulty, please post the error messages you get instead of just saying "it doesn't work." Otherwise we're shooting in the dark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either:

1. Set it to `false` at all the JVM(s) which download classes, and ensure that `java.rmi.server.codebase` is set to something useable at all the JVMs which send objects whose classes may need downloading, or
2. Leave it alone but make sure that every JVM in the system is started with a `java.rmi.server.codebase` property that points to a useable codebase for that JVM.

It's a very strange change to make.  I don't see any security implications, just a nuisance change that changes semantics at all the codebase recipients. With `useCodebaseOnly=true`, you have to set `java.rmi.server.codebase` at the *receiving* JVMs, where otherwise you only have to set it at the sending JVMs. This isn't clear from the documentation.

Comment: It seems to be a response to [this vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-1537). Setting the property back to false should be done with caution.